# python nested 'for' loop breaks too soon

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, textedit

I cant spot what is going on here with this nested loop. The inner (for line in temp:) loop runs great but outer for loop (for cnt in range) only runs once, so that temp is only appended to infile once.

```
with open("temp_inv.ext") as temp:
    with open(infile, 'a') as of:
        for cnt in range(1, sample_cnt):
            for line in temp:
                l = None
                if "INVERSE_MODELING" in line:
                    l = line.replace(smp_num[0], smp_num[cnt])
                if "solutions" in line:
                    l = line.replace(smp_num[0], smp_num[cnt])
                if "netpath" in line:
                    l = line.replace(smp_num[0], smp_num[cnt])
                if l is None:
                    of.write(line)
                else: of.write(l)
```

I have checked that 'sample_cnt' is an integer and 'smp_num' is a valid array.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

To clarify for others that want to use a similar method -

I want to append 'temp' to 'of' after mangling 'temp' by changing a string based on the 'smp_num' array. Addition of the {temp.seek(0)} answered my problem, I had missed that the outer loop was still inside the {with} statement, thus needed to seek before running again.

Comment: `sample_cnt` may be an integer, but what is its value?

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ehm... once you run through lines in the temp file you need to move the file position back with seek(). Do temp.seek(0) somewhere in the outer loop.

Comment: @Mad Wombat _ Thanks, I knew I was missing something silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use seek() to rewind the file once you read all the lines. Use

```
temp.seek(0)
```

somewhere in the outer loop

Comment: cool, maybe you can read people's mind, because I still haven't understood what the goal of the code is

Comment: He does some conditional text mangling and writes either the result or the original line into the of file. He wants to do this multiple times, but doesn't rewind the file position. Not sure what confused you.

Comment: Goal, schmoal. If you have nested loops and the inner loop is reading a file, the problem is *always* a lack of `seek()`.

Comment: I am not so sure he wants to repeat the same operation multiple times. On the very same data, I mean.

Comment: for cnt in range(1, sample_cnt) suggests that he does

Comment: yes, the code looks like it. It'd be nice to know what the goal is. upvoted

Comment: @Pynchia I don't know, mate, I like the mystery :)